# Adding multiple TextBoxes in one column of database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm creating an Inventory System which can add multiple items in a single click. how could I do this? I can already save data but for just a single textbox.

```
//Add new Data if Item Code is not exit;
            {
                OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime) values ('" + txtItem.Text + "','" + txtProduct.Text + "','" + txtQuantity.Text + "','" + time + "')");
                cmdInsert.Connection = con;

                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("You added New " + txtQuantity.Text + " " + txtProduct.Text + " in the list", "New Item");
            }
           con.Close();
```

assuming that I have another textBoxes which are `txtItem2`, `txtProduct2` and `txtQuantity2`. where can I locate those on my `insert into statement`?

Comment: Yet another SQL Injection :| Please, read about parameters first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter

Comment: And after that please elaborate on the question :P

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder sir please see the above added question

Comment: @Jonald Samilo, thanks please refer to "Paweł Dyl's" answer. That is exactly what you should try in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use parameters instead of string concatenation, like below:

```
OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(
    @"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime) values (@ItemCode,@ProductName,@Quantity,@DateAndTime)");
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", txtItem.Text);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", txtProduct.Text);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateAndTime", time);
```

Second, if you need many inserts, use loop. Or, wrap your insert code in function with four parameters `ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime`. Use them instead of direct references to `txtSomething.Text` values, i.e. (pseudocode):

```
InsertRecord(txtItem.Text, txtProduct.Text, ...);
InsertRecord(txtItem2.Text, txtProduduct2.Text, ...);
```

For loop you can write like below:

```
var rows = new[]
{
    new {Item = "item1" /*value from txtItem1*/, Product = "product1", Quantity = "Quantity1" /*should be int?*/},
    new {Item = "item2" /*value from txtItem2*/, Product = "product2", Quantity = "Quantity2"}
};

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(
        @"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime) values (@ItemCode,@ProductName,@Quantity,@DateAndTime)");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", row.Item);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", row.Product);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", row.Quantity);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateAndTime", DateTime.Now);
    cmdInsert.Connection = conn;
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: sir can you please help me create a sample loop for that? assuming there will be a 5 duplicate for my items. how could I do that?

Comment: Also you may not want to create more than one transactions to database. Search how to do bulk insert.

Comment: Thank you so much sir @Pawel. And about the quantity, it should be declare as an int sir.

Comment: sir how can I can save only the textboxes that have values?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure accepting xml as input parameter, and then in the stored procedure  ypu will parse the xml and insert the data to the table,